# How to get the methods from a generic interface being passed into a generic class?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, generics

I have this code below (possibly incorrectly implemented) where I've been trying to create a generic way to use multiple web services (to reduce code redundancy). So far so good up until "ClaimGetAsync()" on the last line.

```
public static class Test {
    public static void TestWebServiceA() {
        var ws = new WebService<ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI>();
        ws.GetClaim(new ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWIClient(), new ARMDevelopment.User(), 
            "https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webserviceawi.svc", "userName", "password");  
    }
     public static void TestWebServiceB() {
        var ws = new WebService<BWDevelopment.WebServiceBW>();
        ws.GetClaim(new BWDevelopment.WebServiceBWClient(), new BWDevelopment.User(), 
            "https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webservicebw.svc", "userName", "password");  
    }
}
public class WebService<T> {             
    public async void GetClaim<TOne, TTwo>(TOne entity1, TTwo entity2, string url, string userName, string password) 
        where TOne : IWebServiceClient, new() // class, new()
        where TTwo : IUser, new()  // limits the TTwo class to implement IUser -> IUser created by me   
    {
        TOne webServiceClient = new TOne(); // entity1;
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
        ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpoint);

        TTwo user = new TTwo(); // entity2;
        user.UserName = await entity1.EncryptValueAsync(userName);
        user.Password = await entity1.EncryptValueAsync(password);

        T wcfClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        var response = wcfClient.ClaimGetAsync(user, 12345); 
    }
}
```

IUser and IWebServiceClient I created and User and WebServiceClient in the web service files inherit them as they are partials.

```
public interface IUser {
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
}

public interface IWebServiceClient
{
     Task<string> EncryptValueAsync(string text);
}
```

But now the last line in the method has no way to discover "ClaimGetAsync" because wcfClient is a generic T

```
var response = wcfClient.ClaimGetAsync(user, 12345);
```

How can I get the generic to find/discover ClaimGetAsync() so that I can use it?

**UPDATE** - A member asked me to post some of the interface code that gets generated from the web service util svcutil.exe:
Here is one from the AWI web service and I have about 20_ more from all the other services we use from this provider

```
namespace WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM
{
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1")]
  [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:trustonline", ConfigurationName="WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.WebServiceAWI")]
    public interface WebServiceAWI
    {
       [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:trustonline/EncryptValue", ReplyAction="urn:trustonline/EncryptValue")]
      [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
      System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> EncryptValueAsync(string text);
    }

   [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:trustonline/ClaimGet", ReplyAction="urn:trustonline/ClaimGet")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="webserviceresult")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.WebServiceResult> ClaimGetAsync(WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.User user, int claimnumber);

}
```

Comment: What type(s) do you expect `T` to be?  Can you add a generic type constraint on `T`?

Comment: T is a specific interface generated from the web service util. so if you look at my code. You'll see ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI is being passed as T. This is a interface that contains methods such as GetClaim(), SearchClaim(), AddClaim(), etc. And there is a different interface like this for each of the 20+ web services we call.

Comment: Do those classes share a common interface containing that method?

Comment: Yes, ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI is the common interface sharing the methods. BUT, there is a common interface for each of the 20+ web services. So I have ex. ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI, BWDevelopment.WebServiceBW, CJDevelopment.WebServiceCJ, etc All these interfaces have the same methods ex. GetClaim(), SearchClaim(), AddClaim(), etc.

Comment: If they all implement `ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI`, and that interface contains the desired method, then `T : ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI` should be your type constraint.

Comment: You can, but `T` would have to satisfy all of the constraints.  Please edit your question with some of these service defintitions and their common interfaces.  Do you have *one* interface that all of these services implement, and that *one* interface contains the desired method?

Comment: This interface "ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI" does contain the methods I need to use such as GetClaim(), SearchClaim(), AddClaim(), etc but I have about 20+ of these interfaces that all need to be passed in and called. So I might pass in ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI or BWDevelopment.WebServiceBW or CJDevelopment.WebServiceCJ

Comment: We are miscommunicating.  Do *all* of these interfaces you mention share a *common* interface?  You have services A, B, and C, which implement interfaces IA, IB, IC, do any of those classes and interfaces implement a *common* interface?

Comment: No they do not. I was wondering if it's possible to create some base interface but don't think so?

Comment: You can create an interface, add this method to that interface, then edit your other interfaces/classes that implement that method so they inherit the new interface accordingly.  Then that interface is your new type constraint.

Comment: Can you provide an example as an answer instead of a comment please?

Comment: Your existing answer is already an example of this, it's just not described very well.

Comment: But if you see from my comments, the existing answer has a small issue I'm not sure how to resolve if even possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202680/discussion-between-user1186050-and-amy).

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IClaimsService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> ClaimGetAsync<TUser>(TUser user, int claimsNumber);
}

public class WebService<T> where T : IClaimsService
{

}
```

Comment: User user is not some object I created it's specific and unique for each web service. So it would be something like namespaceA.webserviceA.User, namespaceB.webserviceb.User. So I can just pass in any User like in your example

Comment: Furthermore, each webservice proxy code file that's generated has a interface it in for ClaimGetAsync. Ex. System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.WebServiceResult> ClaimGetAsync(WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.User user, int claimnumber); Notice how what is passed in and what is returned is very specific to each service

Comment: Just tried your solution and I don't think your solution will work because I have to pass in a specific interface (Ex. ARMDevelopment.WebServiceAWI) from each web service to the constructor.  So when I try it and constructor has a red line that says: "The type 'WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.WebServiceAWI' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'WebService<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WebServices_Development_TrustOnline_ARM.WebServiceAWI' to 'Auto2.API.Helpers.IWebServiceClient"